# I am unable to restore my existing database from C#.net windows application

Tags: c#, mysql

> BasePriority = 'process.BasePriority' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'...

This is the exception I am getting while restoring the database from my .net application.. Here I am providing the code....

```
try
{
    //Read file from C:\
    string path;
    path = filetext.Text;

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
    string input = file.ReadToEnd();
    file.Close();

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlimport.exe";
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
    userid, paswd, server, comboBox1.Text);
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    Console.WriteLine(psi);

    Process process = Process.Start(psi);
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
    process.StandardInput.Close();

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("database is restored");
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to Restore!");
}
```

After the line `process.start(psi).`. it shows that exception....

Plz provide any suggestion....

Comment: I'd suggest putting a break point at your Process.Start(psi) line. View the state of the variables. Then enter that same command at a command prompt. Does it work? Make sure you use exactly what's in comboBox1.Text.

Comment: @Bob command prompt windows opens for a second then closes...so cant see...

Comment: Open a command prompt explicitly, then enter that command. Why would it close?

Comment: Why are you doing StandardInput.Close()?

Comment: @Bob if you could plz tell how to do it...??

Comment: Actually i have seen it from net....

Comment: Yes, but I can't do this right now. Have to go. I might be able to check later. Really, you should open a command prompt yourself (not through code), and enter the command with the same parameters as the code does. See what happens. You may be doing things correctly, but you may not be doing something that mysql allows. Try that and I'll check in later.

Comment: Ok thanks...But plz check it later.....Thanks..

Comment: Okay. Also try putting a breakpoint on the first line of your catch block. Drill into the exception and see if it provides any clues.

Comment: @Bob actually pointer doesn't come to catch block...Whole code of try block is running bt after the line process.start(psi) dos window opens for few seconds and then closes then when i drill into the exception i find invalid operation exception...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the process hasn't started when you try to write to the `StandardInput`. 
Can you try to either call `Thread.Sleep()` or [WaitForInputIdle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx)?

Comment: Well, then the way you are starting the process is the problem. Like Bob already said, what happens when you start mysqlimport.exe via the command line with the same parameters?

Comment: ya i know....I meant to say what does it mean run mysqlimport.exe with same parameter....i have run mysqlimport.exe in command prompt....and it shows many things...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code at this line: psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", userid, paswd, server, comboBox1.Text); Then, when you run mysqlimport on the command line, use those exact same values and see if it works.

Comment: It shows various details like Usage, different variables and boolean options are give etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function it's working fine.Just change mysqlimport.exe with mysql.exe.

### Code

```
public static string RestoreDataBase(string ExeLocation,
    string Fname,
    string DBName,
    string Ip,
    string Uid,
    string Pass)
{
    string sql = "";
    try
    {
        //Read file from C:\
        string path;
        path = Fname;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
        string input = file.ReadToEnd();
        file.Close();

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = ExeLocation;//@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlimport.exe";
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
        Uid, Pass, Ip, DBName);
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        Console.WriteLine(psi);

        Process process = Process.Start(psi);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
        process.StandardInput.Close();

        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();

        sql = "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sql = ex.Message;
    }
    return sql;
}
```

### Calling function

```
string sql = functionclass.RestoreDataBase(@"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe", @"C:\iTelBilling-5-4-2013.sql", "iTelBilling", "localhost", "root", "admin");
```